# Where can I get postal codes for all countries?

Tags: database, geolocation, gis, postal-code

I once read about an open source database for postal codes with geolocation data but now I can't remember its name.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

My guess is that your lost friend is [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/).

Comment: GeoNames is an excellent site, and Marc is incredibly helpful if you can't quite find what you want. I've just emailed him about some geodata I need and he replied quickly with exactly what I needed.

Comment: You can download postal code to name,lat,lng from their site here: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

Comment: geoNames is probably closest you can find of free worldwide postal codes and they are updated daily.  The downside is that they are missing for alot of countries.  GeoNames accomodates for 91 countries, but omits about 160+ other countries found at https://www.geopostcodes.com/resources#countries .  Also be aware that each country classifies areas within differently,  Cities are mostly under "place_name" but also sometimes found under admin_name2 and 3.

Comment: There is also a very good and complete database (paid) at https://mapanet.eu

Answer (score 8):

Find all countries at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) or run a ready-parsed MySQL script (INSERTs):

[Download **delivery_zip.zip**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj95fbx6uk6hstf/delivery_zip.sql.zip?dl=0) (11 Mb)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts you made. You could also zip this 286 MB file that makes it just 11.5MB, hence easy to download. Get the [same file here 11.6 MB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj95fbx6uk6hstf/delivery_zip.sql.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Hello, was anyone able to check if the attached sql file is clean, it is a huge file, my editor Notepad++ cannot even go to the end of the file,

Comment: You can open it using HeidiSQL in a safe testing environment inside a testing database. Use VirtualBox or Docker to create an environment you're not feared to damage. Or even a linux booting from a usb flash-card.

Comment: You can also use my [Big Text Browser](http://blog.gio.palacino.com/big-text-browser/) for opening massive text files, it's totally free.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for an Open GIS database - the main keyword being "GIS". This will help you find results.

The information you're looking for is usually Commercial grade (i.e. you need to pay for the data), but you can see what's available on the open-source GIS websites:

- http://www.osgeo.org/
- http://opensourcegis.org/
- http://freegis.org/

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using this one: https://www.back4app.com/database/back4app/zip-codes-all-countries-in-the-world it's free and very useful!

It's also possible to collaborate with this dataset, in order to improve it even more. :)

Comment: Amazing solution!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Geonames is the place. To be more specific as slacy said

https://download.geonames.org/export/zip/

It has a list of countries' postal codes and it has an allCountries zip file.

And the data is updated daily.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [postal code database](https://www.worldcitiesdatabase.com/) . Its low cost,free updates as well for over a year.
Video demonstration of the database and supported fields on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PzjHzMDKyYw