# writing long view tags

Tags: .net

I want to write a program which would download all post offices given a postal code(pin code) from: http://www.indiapost.gov.in/pin/pinsearch.aspx
Type in: 570001  and press Search. Now see the html source.
The form is passing some encrypted values.
It has some similarity to encode_base64 function in perl/php but I could not decode it.

I'm pasting one line from the code. In the post request this form is sending some encrypted values. **I want to decipher the type of encryption used in .com related modules**:

(I'm tagging javascript,php,.net  because person working in that field may recognize this pattern)

```
<input type="hidden"
 name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"
 value="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"
> /> </div>
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: Daniel whay did you remove php,perl tags? This encryption could be associated with for example perl,php encode_base64 alogorithm. Then why you have not removed html? Encryption is nothing to do with HTML

Comment: deceze thanks how can I decode it using the link you've provided?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's encrypted with a server secret that you would need to know. Please also be careful about the distinction between *encoding* and *encryption*. Why do you want to decrypt it to begin with?

Comment: For postal code search it's returning may be 100 results and it's showing in 10 pages, to click prev, next it's passing this encrypted code. I want to download all the 100 results by writing program, but I'm not able to navigation because may be I need to decode/decrypt it. There are more chances that it is encoded than encrypted. I know it's a govt site, lax department, it should be simple encoding to hide information from automated programs. Postal codes are public but this govt dept is infact selling it in DVD for a price that's why they want to force public to buy it from them!

Comment: It's obviously a .NET viewstate, basically a poor mans session substitute. Read the link, search Google. It may or may not have anything to do with the postal codes, more likely not. It's also a Microsoft invention, which means it's probably not as simple as you assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ASP.NET ecrypted ViewState. It most likely does not contain the values you're looking for, and is specifically designed to be difficult to decrypt client-side. Even if it did have postal-code information in it, trying to hack the encryption would be a) far more trouble than it's worth, and b) on shaky ground legally and ethically.

Unless the DVD costs more than, say, 40 hours of your time as a programmer, I highly recommend you just buy it, or else try [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/) or any of the services in [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308017/where-can-i-get-postal-codes-for-all-countries).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working against the grain, why don't you just use a website that makes the data public:

http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/nearpostoffice.asp

Then if you look at a post office location:

http://www.melissadata.com/lookups/NearPostOffice.asp?po=ALL&zipcode=60611

It displays it table format. If you need this information just screen scrape and make sure if you use this information on your own website to say where you got the information. I don't believe its necessary to do so but it is always a good idea to cite your sources.